# pgbench for postgresql 9.3 for centos where to find it?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

How can I install pgbench for postgresql 9.3?

I have basically set up my postgresql9.3 on centos 64 bit, and it runs fine. No problem at all.

I then installed postgresql93-contrib on my centos machine. But i dont seem to have pgbench? I get command not found?

I execute the following under bash:

```
pgbench -i -U test test
```

any ideas?

Comment: According to [this](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/25391499/dir/redhat_el_6/com/postgresql93-contrib-9.3.1-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm.html) pgbench should be installed as `/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pgbench`, can you check if that file exists?  If so, it's just a matter of correcting your PATH

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is in contrib.  The exact spelling depends on which repo you use, something like `postgresql93-contrib`

It is possible that pgbench will not be in your default path. Then you can run it by executing: `/usr/pgsql-10/bin/pgbench --help`

Comment: postgresql-contrib is the generic name for the package that will install the correct version.

Comment: `yum whatprovides pgbench` is returning `postgresql-contrib` in CentOS 7 for me.

Answer (score 3):

in Centos6

install pgbench

```
yum install postgresql93-contrib
```

then pgbench will appear in /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin

add this path to system

```
vi /etc/profile
```

add /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin to Path

```
source /etc/profile
```

now can run pgbench now